# Can't get a button to align in the middle of a vertical line?

Tags: html, css

I have a header with two parts, a title and a button to the right. I want the button to the right to align in the middle of the line, but I can't seem to get it even with vertical-align. Any suggestions?

```
    <div class="page-header text-center" style="margin-top: 80px">
            <h1 class="glyph" style="margin-right: 100px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Events </h1> 
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs glyph" id="addEvent" style="margin-left:100px vertical-align:middle"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button> 

        </div>
```

The glyph class has a display of inline, so both of the header and button are on the same line.

Comment: I don't really get it.. http://jsfiddle.net/ae9889ox/

Answer (score 1):

Use display: table on the parent and display:table-cell on the child, like so:

```
.page-header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.page-header button {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hx1gmaso/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't place the button on the same line as the heading, which is what the OP seems to be asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Put `vertical-align: middle` on each siblings, in your case **button** and **H1**
If your wrapper **div** has any `height`, add same `line-height` to it.

```
div {
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
}
div > h1 {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div > button {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lima_fil/nnv1s0hs/)

For some more complicated problems, I really like [3-lines solution](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/):

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<h1>` to also have a style of `vertical-align:middle`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mge93c1/2/) (there's some extra styles there for demonstration)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could add:

```
text-align: center
```

To the division the button sits in. I made you an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gckdpodn/)

**EDIT** I am sorry, I did not get your question at first. You should probably try the css calc() function for this. I made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gckdpodn/1/). By calculating 50% margin minus the height of the button you can center the button.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's request to align it in the middle of the line...  This would align it centered by width, not height.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it should work also for the vertical align.

Comment: this only works for square... In your `margin-top: calc(50% - 10px);` actually refers to 50% of the width (odd, I know). See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/gckdpodn/2/

Comment: Lol I made a square by accident, did not even realize that the 50% refer to the width. Good to know thanks!